# Dynamically changing subtitles at various drilldowns in treemap in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, treemap, subtitle, drilldown

I have 5 levels of drilldown in my treemap, and I want to change the subtitle at every drilldown. I came across this code:

> chart.setTitle({ text: drilldownTitle + e.point.name });

which works well for column charts, but I in treemap i have stored data in array format and there is no drilldown id, how can I achieve this functionality for treemap.

```
     $('#container').highcharts({
            series: [{
                type: "treemap",
                layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified'
}],

 subtitle: {
            text: 'Click points to drill down </a>.'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'TreeMap Sample'
        }
}],
```

Comment: Could you provide a live demo of your chart (jsfiddle ideally)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mnidhi/yLng8bfz/  This the live demo, I have been able to change the title during drilldown but drillup is not working. Can u plz help me change back the title at each drillup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Highcharts doesn't offer events like `drillupToNode` & `drilldownToNode` that would ease manipulating the chart's title.

**Workaroud:**

I add title-handling logic to `drillToNode` function and overwrite it:

```
H.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.drillToNode = function(id, redraw) {
  var series = this,
    chart = series.chart,
    nodeMap = series.nodeMap,
    node = nodeMap[id],
    title;
  series.idPreviousRoot = series.rootNode;
  series.rootNode = id;

  if (id === '') {
    series.drillUpButton = series.drillUpButton.destroy();
    title = chart.userOptions.title.text;
  } else {
    series.showDrillUpButton((node && node.name || id));
    title = node.name;
  }

  chart.setTitle({
    text: title
  }, null, false);

  this.isDirty = true; // Force redraw
  if (pick(redraw, true)) {
    this.chart.redraw();
  }
}
```

Original function can be found in this link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/modules/treemap.src.js

`point.events.click` in no longer required while using this code, but chart needs to have the `chart.title.text` property defined initially.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7toez0n5/

Comment: Thank u so much Kamil, this is exactly what I wanted initially. But my aim was to make a navigation path out these. U check out my code here, I have tried workaround --> https://jsfiddle.net/mnidhi/smgL2q59/
But the code u have provided i cant add this functionality, or is there any other way I can show the nav path?

Comment: Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yLoqv0vq/ In `load` event I create `compoundTitle` array. Then I use it in overwritten functions: `drillUp`, `onClickDrillToNode` and `drillToNode`.